# Function doesn't work on iPhone 5 with arc4random

Tags: swift

I have a problem with one of my function: my application run perfectly on iPhone 5s, 6, etc, but on a iPhone 5 I have a problem with my code. When my function is called, I always have this problem:

```
switch choixDeCote {

        case 1 : //Haut
            let MinValue = self.size.width / 8
            let MaxValue = self.size.width - 200
            SpawnX = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
            SpawnX = arc4random_uniform(SpawnX)
            SpawnY = UInt32(self.size.height)
            directionX = Int(arc4random()) % Int(self.frame.size.width)
            print(directionX)
            directionY = 0
            action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(directionX),y: CGFloat(directionY)),duration: 4)
            break
```

And Xcode says that `directionX = Int(arc4random()) % Int(self.frame.size.width)` has a problem, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc4random()` returns a `UInt32`.  On a 32-bit machine like the iPhone 5, this can overflow an `Int`.

I would suggest instead:

```
directionX = Int(Int32(bitPattern: arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.width))))
```

the `Int32(bitPattern:)` is only a precaution and isn't really necessary since the `self.frame.size.width` is much smaller than MAXINT32 so the random number generated won't overflow an `Int`.  You can just do:

```
directionX = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.width)))
```

Comment: The `Int32(bitPattern:)` conversion  is not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks you ,  my application work perfectly now ;)

Comment: @MartinR, Yeah.  Given that the frame width is small it wouldn't overflow the `Int`.  I just felt extra cautious after saying that casting an `UInt32` to and `Int` could crash.